# Create live preview of image (before upload it) using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a preview for image before upload it on the server, using JQuery.

My code, js code:

```
$(function(){
    Test = {
        UpdatePreview: function(obj){
          // if IE < 10 doesn't support FileReader
          if(!window.FileReader){
             // don't know how to proceed to assign src to image tag
          } else {
             var reader = new FileReader();
             var target = null;

             reader.onload = function(e) {
              target =  e.target || e.srcElement;
               $("img").prop("src", target.result);
             };
              reader.readAsDataURL(obj.files[0]);
          }
        }
    };
});
```

My html:

```
    <input type='file' name='browse' onchange='Test.UpdatePreview(this)'  />
<br/><br/>
   <img src="#" alt="test" width="128" height="128" />
```

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aAuMU/

After `onload`, I see the src of image (using Google console application) and it looks like:

`data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD//gAEKgD/4gv4SUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAvoAAAAAAIAAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAH2QADABsA...`

It is a way to get in javascript the base of image and assign to image in case I'm using IE as browser ?

`FileReader` doesn't work in IE < 10.

Comment: Without using 3rd party extensions like `flash` or `silverlight` it is not possible if the browser does not support `FileReader` then you would need to upload it.

Comment: you can create fallback for older browsers by creating serverside solution. Once you choose image it is send to server by ajax call, processed, returned and displayed as thumbnail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need it as getting nice effect then you could use flash like they do in 
https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI

But when i needed to show image to user because i needed to let user select area for croping then i used form inside hidden iframe and uploaded image to server and sent back image data uri so i was able to get data uri and replace image src attribute, then when area was selected i did not send image back as file but as data uri. In old browsers it means you upload image twice, but i did not want to use flash as in some cases flash may also not be installed there.

Answer (score 0):

**LIVE PREVIEW CAN BE DONE IN JQUERY**

We need an onchange event to load the image. img tag is given an ***id = frame***, the function *UpdatePreview()* loads the image immediately after the image or file is selected.

```js
function UpdatePreview(){
    $('#frame').attr('src', URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='file' name='browse' oninput='UpdatePreview()'/>
<img src="#" id ="frame" alt="test" width="128" height="128" />
```

Answer (score -5):

Instead of

```
$("img").prop("src", target.result);
```

write

```
$("#ImageId").attr("src", target.result);
```

Where `ImageId` is the ID of your img tag.