# How to preview image before upload in HTML?

Tags: javascript, upload, preview

I have modified the function

```
<script>
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
$("#upload").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
});
</script>
```

and included this input in my form in the body element:

```
<input type="file" name="uploaded_files" id="upload"/>
<img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
```

I have also included jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It’s working in JsFiddle, but it’s not working on my localhost.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694437/how-to-preview-image-before-uploading-in-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with what you have done, neither with your script JS block. You can go and check on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/3317/).

---

Just make sure you are loading the `jQuery` library correctly since your script depends on.

Answer (score 1):

Try Like

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/LvsYc/3316/)