# Javascript image upload and display

Tags: javascript, php, html

My basic task is select image and display it,without saving it in database.

For this

1.I have made a select tag in html,through which I can upload the image.

2.I have made a blank image tag in which at there is no image source,alternate is upload image.

3.select tag has onchange javascript event handler which calls javascript function changeimage.

```
<script>
       function changeimage()
       {
            document.form_name.imagetag.src=document.form_name.filetag.value;
       }
</script>
```

In above Code

form_name : Is the name of my form

```
<form name = "form_name">
```

imagetag : Is the name of my Img tag

```
<Img src=" " name = "imagetag">
```

filetag : Is the name of my

```
<input type="file" name = "filetag" onchange="changeimage()">
```

I have save file using php extension.And when I try to print the value of filetag it shows "C:\fakepath\image.png",display this address for all image.
I have save my php file in www location.

I am using window 7,wamp server and chrome latest version.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12369027/3020926
(10s of google btw)

Comment: if I am not wrong they have use jQuery but I want through javascript.

Comment: There are more answers on the page I posted. One is even pure JS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML - Display image after selecting filename](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368910/html-display-image-after-selecting-filename)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may want to checkout this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19649483/3046413) (where my code derives from). It involves a little bit of jQuery but if you truly must write it out in pure JS, here you go.

**Note:** I modified your tags to conform to the JS below. Also try to stay away from writing any inline scripts. Always good to keep your HTML and JS loosely coupled.

```js
var fileTag = document.getElementById("filetag"),
    preview = document.getElementById("preview");
    
fileTag.addEventListener("change", function() {
  changeImage(this);
});

function changeImage(input) {
  var reader;

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      preview.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="filetag">
<img src="" id="preview">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `Image()` constructor. It creates a new `HTML Image Element`.

Example -

```
document.getElementById("filetag").addEventListener("change", function(e) {

  let newImg = new Image(width, height);

  // Equivalent to above -> let newImg = document.createElement("img");

  newImg.src = e.target.files[0];
  newImg.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);

  output.appendChild(newImg);
});
```

Reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

Answer (score 0):

You need one input tag to upload file and a image tag to render on the site.

The HTML and Javascript should look like

```js
const renderFile = () => {
  const render = document.querySelector('img')
  const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]
  const reader = new FileReader();
  
  
  reader.addEventListener('load' , ()=> {
    render.src = reader.result;
  }, false)

  if(file){
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type = 'file' onchange = 'renderFile()' >
<br>
<br>
<img src = "" alt='rendered image' id='rendered-image'  >
```

Simply on every upload the web page will show the image uploaded
You can Style the height and width of the image according to the need