# Jquery: Create Image Preview from Image Object (e.dataTransfer.files)

Tags: jquery, upload, coffeescript

So far I have been trying to upload image using ajax, to upload it I use `e.dataTansfer` like this:

```
    uploadarea = document.getElementById("upload-area")
    uploadarea.addEventListener "dragenter", dragEnterLeave, false
    uploadarea.addEventListener "dragleave", dragEnterLeave, false
    uploadarea.addEventListener "dragover", ((e) ->
        e.stopPropagation()
        e.preventDefault()
        ok = e.dataTransfer and e.dataTransfer.types and e.dataTransfer.types.indexOf("Files") >= 0
        if ok 
            $("div#upload-area").text("Drop Image here").removeClass("not-available").addClass "over"
        else
            $("div#upload-area").text("Only File Allowed!").removeClass("over").addClass "not-available"
    )
    uploadarea.addEventListener "drop", ((e) ->
        e.stopPropagation()
        e.preventDefault()
        $("div#upload-area").removeClass().text "Drop Image here"
        image_file = e.dataTransfer.files[0]
        console.log image_file
        $("p.file-relative-path").text image_file.name //here I tried to get relative path to make the preview

)
```

I have been trying to create a preview image before upload. How to achieve it with this code?

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083626/create-live-preview-of-image-before-upload-it-using-jquery