# Preview multiple images before upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image

I want to preview multiple images before upload. Secondly I want to remove/deselect the selected file if I choose wrong file. I am working on jquery code but it preview one image at a time. Also I want to select multiple images at a single time.

Here is the **jquery** code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//To add new input file field dynamically, on click of "Add More Files" button below function will be executed
$('#add_more').click(function() {
    $(this).before($("<div/>", {id: 'filediv'}).fadeIn('slow').append(
            $("<input/>", {name: 'file[]', type: 'file', id: 'file'}),        
            $("<br/><br/>")
            ));
});

//following function will executes on change event of file input to select different file   
$('body').on('change', '#file', function(){
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
             abc += 1; //increementing global variable by 1

            var z = abc - 1;
            var x = $(this).parent().find('#previewimg' + z).remove();
            $(this).before("<div id='abcd"+ abc +"' class='abcd'><img id='previewimg" + abc + "' src=''/></div>");

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

            $(this).hide();
            $("#abcd"+ abc).append($("<img/>", {id: 'img', src: 'x.png', alt: 'delete'}).click(function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            }));
        }
    });

//To preview image     
function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    $('#previewimg' + abc).attr('src', e.target.result);
};

$('#upload').click(function(e) {
    var name = $(":file").val();
    if (!name)
    {
        alert("First Image Must Be Selected");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
});
```

Here is the **HTML** code

```
<div id="formdiv">
            <h2>Multiple Image Upload Form</h2>
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
                First Field is Compulsory. Only JPEG,PNG,JPG Type Image Uploaded. Image Size Should Be Less Than 100KB.
                <hr/>
                <div id="filediv"><input name="file[]" multiple type="file" id="file"/></div><br/>

                <input type="button" id="add_more" class="upload" value="Add More Files"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" id="upload" class="upload"/>
            </form>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <!-------Including PHP Script here------>
            <?php include "upload.php"; ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: http://robertnyman.com/2010/12/16/utilizing-the-html5-file-api-to-choose-upload-preview-and-see-progress-for-multiple-files/   you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can see this topic , I think it has what you need.
**[Create live preview of image (before upload it) using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083626/create-live-preview-of-image-before-upload-it-using-jquery)**

also you can give a try with that

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Show-Display-image-preview-before-upload-using-jQuery.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples on http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multifile/

Maybe you can extract the parts of their code to write your custom.

Answer (score 0):

For images preview you can use the `URL.createObjectURL` javascript function . Example:

```
$('body').on('change', '#file', function(){
     if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
           var URL  = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
           var img  = $('<img />').attr('src', URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0] ) );
     }
});
```

If you need a full uploader you can also try this: http://www.albanx.com/ajaxuploader/ or other online examples